# Can't log to Stack Exchange using Google (OpenID) when already logged in to Stack Overflow

Tags: support, login, openid

I had registered my account through Google (AFAIK it was on Stack Overflow, but don't really remember), and I'm logged in on Stack Overflow. However, when I went to chat.stackexchange.com domain (including any of the chatrooms), I wasn't logged in. When I attempted to log in using my Google account it said the user with that email doesn't exist and it offered to create a new account.

Logging in on Super User did make everything fine and automatically logged me across SE as well (including the chat), but it also left me wondering what would've happened if I proceeded with the sign up with the already existing email.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I recall right, chat.stackexchange.com directs you to log in on stackexchange.com rather than a Q&A site. se.com, unfortunately, has a somewhat weird setup where it tries to create a "profile" for you on itself even though it's not really needed in your specific situation.

What would've happened if you had gone ahead with sign up, is you'd end up with a read-only profile on stackexchange.com and have been otherwise logged in just fine.

We should really look at what we would need to do before we can move off of having user profiles on se.com entirely one of these days, since they do little except cause confusion.

Comment: You're right. I know it's nothing major but it's a confusing detail. It did offer me to "log in with StackExchange account", but since I don't have email/password pair for the network account it wasn't a sensible thing to do.